# Multiple COUNT(*) display on one page

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably super simple - but i am tearing my hair out.
database is using cPanel (MariaDB 10.1.28)

Heres the scenario

- 1 Table Called "WARNINGS"
- 1 column called "WARNING_REASON" (VARCHAR)
  warning_reason contains various "reasons"
- 1 column called "WARNING_LEVEL" (VARCHAR)
  This contains either "VERBAL", "LEVEL 1" or "LEVEL 2"

I need to output this data in php on a 5 column table

- Warning Reason
- Total number of rows in table grouped by warning_reason
- Total of rows that match "VERBAL" grouped by warning_reason
- Total of rows that match "LEVEL 1" grouped by warning_reason
- Total of rows that match "LEVEL 2" grouped by warning_reason

Comment: May I ask what have you tried?

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT warning_reason, COUNT(*) as warning_total
  FROM lasersports_ref.warnings
  GROUP by warning_reason'; 
Which gets me the total of warnings, but im struggling with the rest of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subqueries to accomplish this:

```
SELECT t1.warning_reason
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warnings s1 WHERE s1.warning_reason = t1.warning_reason) AS total_count
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warnings s2 WHERE s2.warning_reason = t1.warning_reason AND s2.warning_level = \'VERBAL\') AS verbal_count
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warnings s3 WHERE s3.warning_reason = t1.warning_reason AND s3.warning_level = \'LEVEL 1\') AS level1_count
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warnings s4 WHERE s4.warning_reason = t1.warning_reason AND s4.warning_level = \'LEVEL 2\') AS level2_count
FROM warnings t1
GROUP BY t1.warning_reason
```

Comment: one semantic recommendation,  instead of COUNT(*) use a specific field, for instance: COUNT(id).

Comment: yea it shows SQL syntax errors in php, but in phpmyadmin works exactly how i need it too. legend. ill somehow figure it out :)

Comment: once i figure out these sytax errors, how would i go only showing the rows that have a certain column in it. eg.

all of the above needs to still happen but, i only need to count/show the records from the "events" column that match "solos"

Sorry to be a pain

Comment: You can add more conditions the same way using ` AND t1.event = \'solos\'` and ` AND s_.event = \'solos\'` in every relevant subquery. Another way is to add `event` to every `warning_reason` and get a row for each event.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Kind of depends on the DBMS used which way is the best/fastest. But the field used should be `not null` to get the same result, usually the primary key works fine. For me, I usually use `count(*)`. There are many questions here on stackoverflow discussing count(*) vs. count(id) vs. count(1) => Not a big difference though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
select warning_reason,
    count(*) as total_warnings,
    sum(warning_level = 'VERBAL')  as verbal_warnings,
    sum(warning_level = 'LEVEL 1') as level1_warnings,
    sum(warning_level = 'LEVEL 2') as level2_warnings
from warnings
group by warning_reason
```

This is shorter and probably faster than running multiple subselects.

Note that in MySQL boolean expression like `warning_level = 'VERBAL'` return either `1` or `0` (or `NULL` if `warning_level is NULL`).

If you want a standard compliant query you can change the line to

```
sum(case when warning_level = 'VERBAL' then 1 else 0 end) as verbal_warnings,
```

or

```
sum(case warning_level when 'VERBAL' then 1 else 0 end) as verbal_warnings,
```

or

```
count(case warning_level when 'VERBAL' then 1 else null end) as verbal_warnings,
```

since NULL is the default value for ELSE you can also skip it

```
count(case warning_level when 'VERBAL' then 1 end) as verbal_warnings,
```

The following also works in MySQL, but I'm not sure if other systems will evaluate it the same way:

```
count(warning_level = 'VERBAL' or null) as verbal_warnings,
```